# So I am having a problem with the following method, and have no clue why it doesnt work for three out of 9 cases?

Tags: java, stack, queue, priority-queue

Write a method called isConsecutive that accepts a PriorityQueue of integers as a parameter and returns true if the queue contains a sequence of consecutive integers starting from the front of the queue. Consecutive integers are integers that come one after the other, as in 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, etc., so if the queue stores [7, 8, 9, 10, 11], your method should return true. (Also return true if passed an empty queue.) If your method modifies the state of the queue during its computation, it should restore the queue before it returns. You may use one stack or queue as auxiliary storage.

```
public boolean isConsecutive(PriorityQueue<Integer> q){

    if(q.isEmpty()){return true;}
    boolean checker = true;
    Object[] other = q.toArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < other.length-1; i++){
        if (checker == false) return checker;
        checker = (int) other[i] < (int) other[i+1];
    }
    return checker;
}
```

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment, so I won't give an exact answer, but the problem is with other[i] < other[i+1]. This is only checking if the number is less than the next value, which isn't necessarily consecutive. With your conditions of just being "less than", then [7, 10, 13, 25] would also return true, which isn't what you want.

Comment: @Tekkerue dang I actually just realized what I was doing wrong XD got it working, thanks! btw not a hw assignment just learning the language XD

Comment: Ah, ok. The question read like a specific coding homework problem. lol 
With problems like this it's always best to get a hint to be pointed in the right direction so you can figure out the problem instead of just being given the answer. As an additional point, try removing your "checker" boolean completely, you can do this problem without it and it will make the method a little clearer.

Comment: @Tekkerue thank you so much!